# ASP .NET Core - Windows authentication on IIS and problem with Domains

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis, active-directory, windows-authentication

The problem is:
I have application which running on IIS with windows authenticate enabled, and others disabled. We have 2 domains, lets call them Domain A(internal) and Domain B(external). Domain A does not trust Domain B, but Domain B trust Domain A. What I want to achieve is that Domain B can access application. I have logic in code, which redirect user to web login form if coming from Domain B. Problem is, my application will always prompt when user coming from Domain B. Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: Is it possible to configure a trust relationship between Domain A and Domain B? This will allow users from domain B to authenticate to domain A, if possible, and then access the application without being prompted for credentials.

Comment: @YurongDai Sadly, our client won't do that so we have very limited options

Comment: Maybe you can use a reverse proxy between the IIS server and domain B users, the reverse proxy can handle the authentication and forward the request to the IIS server, you can use different authentication for different domains.